# How to resample time series dataframe to show average hourly data?

Tags: python, dataframe, time, series

I am aware that pandas resample function has **hourly ** rule. However, it returns the average for every hour for the whole dataset.

When using that method (df.Value.resample('H').mean()), I get the following output:

| Time&date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 23 |
| 2021-01-01 01:00:00 | 25 |

However, I would like hourly resample of data which shows the average values throughout the year for the whole dataset (not everyday hourly).

What I want:

| Time&date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00:00 | 55 |
| 01:00:00 | 24 |

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

groupby can give you the result you want. Can you try this?

```
dfx=df.groupby(df['date_column'].dt.hour).mean()
```